# theta dot right place

Tags: symbols

I have small problem:
how to get top of the symbol dot in the right place? With my code the result is like in the picture below:[image]
What I want is like in this picture:
[image]
Here is the code:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:angspeed}
\overline{\boldsymbol{\upomega}}=\overline{\mathbf{G}}\dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\end{equation}
```

The top lines are "good". Or with "`\bar`" the line is too short for omega and with `\overline` the line is too long, but better.

I use these packages:

```
\usepackage{upgreek}
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%fonts and utf8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading also the `bm` package should immediately improve the situation.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\bar{\boldsymbol{\upomega}}=
\bar{\mathbf{G}}\dot{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can also use the shorthand `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`. I loaded NewTX instead of `txfonts`: it's the successor package and fixes several of the shortcomings of the original package.

I'm not sure I'd mix `upgreek` with NewTX, but the decision is yours.

The code `\LoadClass` should *never* be used in a document, it's only for class files.

[image]